# Write a program that extracts the contents of an RPM file on Windows

Tags: c, windows, qt, rpm

I am looking to write a program that will extract the contents of an RPM file and do some validation checks.  I'll be using Qt for the interface so that the program can be run in Windows and Linux.

Are there any suggestions for extracting the contents for an RPM file on Windows?  I would prefer a C library, but other suggestions are welcome also.

Answer (score 1):

[rpmlib](http://www.rpm.org/) looks like what you are after.